# How to properly benchmark code in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, benchmarking, timing

I want to time multiple functions and compare them to see which one is faster.

So far I've found the [perf_hooks](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/perf_hooks.html) module, is this the best way? If it is, how can I get the average of multiple executions for a function? This is what I have:

```
import { performance, PerformanceObserver } from 'perf_hooks';

const MAX_STRINGS = 10**6;
const STRING_SIZE = 6;
const TEST_STRINGS = [...new Array(MAX_STRINGS)].map(() => Math.random().toString().substring(STRING_SIZE));

function concatMethodLoop() {
    const result = '';
    for (const key of TEST_STRINGS) {
        const condition = `#${key} = :${key}`;
        result.concat(result ? ` AND ${condition}` : `${condition}`);
    }
    return result;
}

function concatAssignmentLoop() {
    let result = '';
    for (const key of TEST_STRINGS) {
        const condition = `#${key} = :${key}`;
        result += result ? ` AND ${condition}` : `${condition}`;
    }
    return result;
}

function joinLoop() {
    const keys: string[] = [];
    for (const key of TEST_STRINGS) {
        keys.push(`#${key} = :${key}`);
    }
    return keys.join(' AND ');
}

function joinMap() {
    return TEST_STRINGS.map(key => `#${key} = :${key}`).join(' AND ');
}

const performanceObserver = new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
    for (const entry of entryList.getEntries()) {
        console.log(`${entry.name}: ${entry.duration} ms`);
    }
});

performanceObserver.observe({ entryTypes: ['function'] });

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    performance.timerify(concatAssignmentLoop)();
    performance.timerify(joinLoop)();
    performance.timerify(concatMethodLoop)();
    performance.timerify(joinMap)();
}
```

Output:

```
concatAssignmentLoop: 623.777999997139 ms
joinLoop: 419.27210000157356 ms
concatMethodLoop: 36.11939999461174 ms
joinMap: 318.1768000125885 ms
concatAssignmentLoop: 547.4036999940872 ms
joinLoop: 313.0974000096321 ms
concatMethodLoop: 111.02349999547005 ms
joinMap: 353.0567000210285 ms
concatAssignmentLoop: 508.7500999867916 ms
joinLoop: 297.3352999985218 ms
concatMethodLoop: 21.475600004196167 ms
joinMap: 457.35159999132156 ms
concatAssignmentLoop: 544.6088999807835 ms
joinLoop: 300.81810000538826 ms
concatMethodLoop: 25.844999998807907 ms
joinMap: 289.18080002069473 ms
concatAssignmentLoop: 661.5806000232697 ms
joinLoop: 300.47850000858307 ms
concatMethodLoop: 18.604999989271164 ms
joinMap: 326.6128999888897 ms
```

which is just the `timerify` functions I call but repeated, but I want to get the average of each function.
I tried using a Map object and modifying its entries inside the callback of `PerformanceObserver` but it didn't work.

[benchmark.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/benchmark.js) hasn't been updated in 4 years and it seems like it doesn't support TypeScript.